# are there any ways to Enable VT-x from windows not from bios? ( my bios has password that i forgot )

Tags: android, android-studio

i want start creating android app,  but in android studio it says that i need to Enable VT-x ,  but my bios has password  and i forgot it,
are there anyway to enable it from windows?

Comment: Sounds to me that the proper fix would be to actually gain access to your BIOS. I think VT-x is only required for emulators, so you might want to try to debug on a device instead

Comment: well i still didnt found any way to fix bios problem... do you have any good soultion? my laptop is lenovo

Comment: That should be a different question altogether

Comment: yeah, if i didnt get answer on this, i will switch on the bios problem